# ThreadFactory newThread() method called only once for each submit() call in ThreadPoolExectutor

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to assign a number for each of `MyRunnable` submitted to `ThreadPoolExecutor` but I did not succeed.

**My code snippet:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
   String name;
   static int threadNo = 0;

   public SimpleThreadFactory (String name){
       this.name = name;
   }
   public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
     ++threadNo;
     System.out.println("thread no:"+threadNo);
     return new Thread(r,name+":"+threadNo );
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        SimpleThreadFactory factory = new SimpleThreadFactory("Ravindra");
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,5,10,TimeUnit.SECONDS,new ArrayBlockingQueue(100),factory);
        for ( int i=0; i < 10; i++){
            executor.submit(new MyRunnable());
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
 }

 class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
     public void run(){
         System.out.println("Runnable:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
     }
 }
```

My expectation:

`executor.submit(new MyRunnable());` should call newThread in ThreadFactory for each submit on executor. But in reality, it happened only once.

Output:

```
thread no:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
Runnable:Ravindra:1
```

***Why submit() is not creating new thread for each submitted Runnable task?***

***How can I assign a sequence number to each of MyRunnable submitted to executor?***

Thanks in advance

Comment: There was probably no need for more than 1 thread in the pool to handle all the tasks. After all, this is what executor services are there to do.

Comment: Got it :) What a simple mistake from my end? I mapped Thread to Runnable Task and forgot to that ThreadFactory is for ExecutorService thread.

Comment: I got 5 threads (max threads)  when I changed the code to submit 1000 tasks. @ biziclop: Your comment corrected my thought process with-in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the interaction between the CorePoolSize and the queue.

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> "If corePoolSize or more threads are running, the Executor always
>   prefers queuing a request rather than adding a new thread."

and

> "If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize
>   threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is
>   full."

So currently, your tasks get queued until there is space in the CorePoolSize (i.e. when your currently executing task finishes), so you never use more than 1 thread, currently.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers explain why there have not been more than one thread. My proposal on how to achieve what you actually wanted is this:

For a start, count the instances of the runnable, not the threads they are run on: For example like this ->

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    private static long _mySequenceCounter = 0; // Maybe use an AtomicLong?
    private final long mySeqNo;

    MyRunnable(){ mySeqNo = ++_mySequenceCounter; }

// Your other stuff here

}
```

Inside run-method, you could rename the current thread if that is sufficient for your requirement. Or you could just output the runnable id and leave the Threads name. That has the advantage that you will know, which thread was reused for which task ... if that has any value to you.

Remark: Above snippet is only to lay out the idea of how to meet your requirement to identify the task. Of course you could improve it if you need thread-safety (snippet could be problematic if `MyRunnables` are created on more than 1 thread).

`long` should give you quite a lot of sequence numbers, but mind that even long will roll over at some point. So you might want to address this if your application runs very long and has a high frequency of new `MyRunnable`s.

Answer (score 1):

See `ThreadPoolExecutor` JavaDoc under [Core and maximum pool sizes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), .... If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created **only if the queue is full**.

To get your code to make more threads I changed this bit:

```
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                // Core pool size
                5,
                // Max pool size
                5,
                // Resize time
                1,
                // Resize time units
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                // Queue of runnables - I CHANGED THIS TO 10
                new ArrayBlockingQueue(10),
                // Factory to use for threads.
                factory);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            executor.submit(new MyRunnable());
        }
```

Comment: Explanation, why there have not been more threads created: OK, but OP did not want to force more threads. He wanted to have a counter on the executed tasks rather than on the threads (see my answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try to add a sleep to your "run" method : here the execution time is probably too short to require many thread...

Comment: In this case i think he just want to test the Executor.